# check if a number is present in a list, app engine templates

Tags: python, google-app-engine, loops, django-templates, conditional-statements

I am trying to generate a board (10X10) using the app engine templates and html table. So this means basically putting a break after 10 iterations of the loop. How can I acieve this using the app engine's inbuilt template engine (django 0.96)?

#### Update

Lukes [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493275/insert-break-automatically-after-10-iterations-in-app-engine-template/4493418#4493418) solved my problem of automatically inserting the break.
But I still need to find a way to check for each number if it is present in a list and give it a specific class. Is there any way to achieve something like this:

```
{% for number in list }
  <td {% if number in another_list %}class="special"{% endif %}>{{number}}</td>
{% endfor }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point you might be better off writing your own templatetag, or using something like [smartif](https://bitbucket.org/tghw/django-smartif/overview), which should let you do `{% if foo in bar %}`.

Comment: I considered that but how do I load custom template tags?

Comment: Create a module called `templatetags` under your project, and inside it put a file like `smartif.py` - inside that, paste the smartif code. Then, in your template, you can do `{% load smartif %}` to load up the tag.

Comment: I created a directory templatags with empty __init__.py and smartif.py but it didn't work :(

Comment: Define "didn't work" - was there an error? Did your page still display?

Comment: no, Template syntax error: template tag library not found error

Comment: http://daily.profeth.de/2008/04/using-custom-django-template-helpers.html should walk you through it.

Answer (score 5):

Does 0.96's templatetags have [divisibleby](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby)? That seems like it'd do the trick:

```
{% for end_number in end_numbers %}
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"10" %}
      </tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be pre-processing the data in your code to be more easily usable in the template. Break up your array of 100 elements into a nested array of 10 arrays of 10 elements each, and provide the information needed there to assign a CSS class to them.

Answer (score 0):

Include a counter (i) which increments during each loop and use an if statement to reset i to 1 and draw the break when it reaches 10.